# LinkedIn oAuth - Accessing simple read only public data - no posting etc

Tags: php, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm trying to do a very basic setup of LinkedIn - accessing public profile data about people.

I've tried several ways of accessing with oAuth over several hours. I'm not getting anywhere.

All the existing class structures et'al seem to help with accessing a user's account to post, or add friends, find a fish etc. I don't need any of that. I just want to get basic profile data.

Some code of latest attempts; but I don't get it past here:-

```
$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$signature_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
$req_req = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, NULL, "GET", $linkedInURL . "/uas/oauth/requestToken");
$req_req->sign_request($signature_method, $consumer, NULL);         
$signed_url = $req_req->to_url();
```

That should gives me a signed request of:-

```
https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?oauth_consumer_key=xxx&oauth_nonce=xx&oauth_signature=xxxx&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1316530337&oauth_version=1.0
```

Obviously, that's not what I need to get data. But, just out of interest I checked the URL with the API data request, as such:-
    http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fchrisvoss:public?oauth_consumer_key=xxx&oauth_nonce=xxx&oauth_signature=xxx&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1316529463&oauth_version=1.0

And got :-

```
<error>
 <status>401</status>
  <timestamp>1316531835564</timestamp>
  <request-id>L8A1M85MWN</request-id>
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>
        [unauthorized].OAU:tm6i3ke827xz|*01|*01|*01:1316529463:MSFHS3f4iaG9pg2gWYlf22W4NPo=
     </message>
</error>
```

I'm just a bit clueless here. I know everyone says it's tears to implement oAuth and Linkedin. But, I don't need half of what most need, so how do I get to the basic data is only my question.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try To Use the following code

   session_start();
require_once("OAuth.php");  



$domain = "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth";
$sig_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();



$test_consumer = new OAuthConsumer("DEHYU99peS88wDDAFOcSm3Af5VO1tdrdgq1xPu_fpSSjsqPcoeABUs_NCyY33WIH", "gZrZr2-7s80CEsGpAHqFgREMbRWkR3L8__tkje3j-oKtIDlmn5KCR6bXD8i0HFp1", NULL);
$callback = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?action=getaccesstoken";



# First time through, get a request token from LinkedIn.
if (!isset($_GET['action'])) {

        $req_req = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($test_consumer, NULL, "POST", $domain . "/requestToken");
        $req_req->set_parameter("oauth_callback", $callback); # part of OAuth 1.0a - callback now in requestToken
        $req_req->sign_request($sig_method, $test_consumer, NULL);

        $ch = curl_init();
        // make sure we submit this as a post
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ''); //New Line

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
                $req_req->to_header()
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $domain . "/requestToken");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        //print_r($req_req);  //<---- add this line

        //print("$output\n");  //<---- add this line

        parse_str($output, $oauth);


        # pop these in the session for now - there's probably a more secure way of doing this! We'll need them when the callback is called.

        $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $oauth['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $oauth['oauth_token_secret'];



        # Redirect the user to the authentication/authorisation page. This will authorise the token in LinkedIn
        Header('Location: ' . $domain . '/authorize?oauth_token=' . $oauth['oauth_token']);
        #print 'Location: ' . $domain . '/authorize?oauth_token=' . $oauth['oauth_token']; // <---- add this line


} else {
        # this is called when the callback is invoked. At this stage, the user has authorised the token.
        # Now use this token to get a real session token!

        //print "oauth_token = [[".$_REQUEST['oauth_token']."]]\n";echo "<br/><br/>";

        $req_token = new OAuthConsumer($_REQUEST['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'], 1);
        $acc_req = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($test_consumer, $req_token, "POST", $domain . '/accessToken');
        $acc_req->set_parameter("oauth_verifier", $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);  # need the verifier too!
        $acc_req->sign_request($sig_method, $test_consumer, $req_token);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ''); //New Line
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
                $acc_req->to_header()
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $domain . "/accessToken");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        if(curl_errno($ch)){
            echo 'Curl error 1: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        parse_str($output, $oauth);


        $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $oauth['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $oauth['oauth_token_secret'];
        # Now you have a session token and secret. Store these for future use. When the token fails, repeat the above process.
        //$endpoint = "http://in.linkedin.com/in/intercom"; # need a + symbol here.
        $endpoint = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,industry,educations,site-standard-profile-request)";
        //$req_token = new OAuthConsumer($oauth['oauth_token'], $oauth['oauth_token_secret'], 1);
        $req_token = new OAuthConsumer($oauth['oauth_token'],$oauth['oauth_token_secret'], 1);
        //$profile_req = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($test_consumer, $req_token, "GET", $endpoint, array("name" => "intercom")); # but no + symbol here!
        $profile_req = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($test_consumer,$req_token, "GET", $endpoint, array());
        $profile_req->sign_request($sig_method, $test_consumer, $req_token);

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
                $profile_req->to_header()
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);


        if(curl_errno($ch)){
            echo 'Curl error 2: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        //header ("Content-Type:text/xml");  
        //print $output;

        $myFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/oauth/linkedin.xml";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        //$stringData = "Bobby Bopper\n";
        fwrite($fh, $output);
        fclose($fh);

        //Initialize the XML parser
        global $currentTag;
        global $profileArray;
        $parser=xml_parser_create();

        //Function to use at the start of an element
        function start($parser,$element_name,$element_attrs) {
            $element_name   =   strtolower($element_name);
            global $currentTag;
            $currentTag = $element_name;
            /*switch($element_name) {
                case "person":
                $currentTag = $element_name;
                break;
                case "headline":
                echo "headline: ";
                break;
                case "school-name":
                echo "school-name: ";
                break;
                case "degree":
                echo "degree: ";
                break;
                case "field-of-study":
                echo "field-of-study: ";
            }*/
        }

        //Function to use at the end of an element
        function stop($parser,$element_name) {}

        //Function to use when finding character data
        function char($parser,$data){

            //echo $data;
            global $currentTag;
            global $profileArray;
            switch($currentTag) {

                /* case "member-url":
                if(!isset($profileArray['member-url'])) {
                    $profileArray['member-url'] =   $data;//echo $profileArray['industry'];
                }
                break;*/
                 case "id":
                if(!isset($profileArray['id'])) {
                    $profileArray['id'] =   $data;//echo $profileArray['industry'];
                }
                break;

                 case "site-standard-profile-request":
                if(!isset($profileArray['site-standard-profile-request'])) {
                    $profileArray['site-standard-profile-request']  =   $data;//echo $profileArray['industry'];
                }
                break;
                case "first-name":
                if(!isset($profileArray['first-name'])) {
                    $profileArray['first-name'] =   $data;//echo $profileArray['industry'];
                }
                break;

                case "last-name":
                if(!isset($profileArray['last-name'])) {
                    $profileArray['last-name']  =   $data;//echo $profileArray['industry'];
                }
                break;
                case "industry":
                if(!isset($profileArray['industry'])) {
                    $profileArray['industry']   =   $data;//echo $profileArray['industry'];
                }
                break;
                case "headline":
                if(!isset($profileArray['headline'])) {
                    $profileArray['headline']   =   $data;
                }   
                break;
                case "school-name":
                if(!isset($profileArray['school-name'])) {
                    $profileArray['school-name']    =   $data;
                }
                break;
                case "degree":
                if(!isset($profileArray['degree'])) {
                    $profileArray['degree'] =   $data;
                }
                break;
                case "field-of-study":
                if(!isset($profileArray['field-of-study'])) {
                    $profileArray['field-of-study'] =   $data;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        //Specify element handler
        xml_set_element_handler($parser,"start","stop");

        //Specify data handler
        xml_set_character_data_handler($parser,"char");

        //Open XML file
        $fp=fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/oauth/linkedin.xml","r");

        //Read data
        while ($data=fread($fp,4096)) {
            xml_parse($parser,$data,feof($fp)) or
            die (sprintf("XML Error: %s at line %d",
            xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($parser)),
            xml_get_current_line_number($parser)));
        }

        //Free the XML parser
        xml_parser_free($parser);
        print_r($profileArray);
        getCurrentCookieValue($name)

}
```

Comment: Interesting... Now you seem to be getting somewhere. However, it appears the user has got to be logged into LinkedIn to get this data. Is that the ONLY way I'm guessing? And is this your app it currently auths with or a global one?

Comment: user has to log in to linked .as far as i know every api for these sites such as facebook,linkedin,twitter always ask user to allow any aplication accessing their profile data.if you want to do it either way let me know

Comment: Further to this, potentially a new question - I've noticed I can't iFrame the API Auth/Request page. It reloads into the whole window. Have you experienced that?

Comment: if you tried above code you can see the data is captured in a array so you can use it anywhere in your site.sorry but i am little bit literate in using iframes .

Comment: How do we use this with the new scope fields to get the email address?

Comment: From Where I can download the OAuth.php file ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use linkedIn [javascript API](https://developer.linkedin.com/javascript) to retrieve profile information